# split existed list based on the repeated word

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried to split a list into new list. Here's the initial list:

```
initList =['PTE123', '', 'I', 'am', 'programmer', 'PTE345', 'based', 'word', 
       'title', 'PTE427', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

If I want to split the list based on the PTExyz to new list which looks:

```
newList = ['PTE123 I am programmer', 'PTE345 based word title',  'PTE427 how are you']
```

How should I develop proper algorithm for general case with repeated item PTExyz?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm will be something like this.

Iterate over the list. Find a the string `s` that starts with `PTE`. Assign it to a `temp` string which is initialized as an empty string. Add every next string `s` with `temp` unless that string starts with `PTE`. In that case, if the `temp` string is not empty then append it with your `result` list else add the string with `temp`.

```
ls = ['PTE123', '', 'I', 'am', 'programmer', 'PTE345', 'based', 'word', 'title', 'PTE427', 'how', 'are', 'you']

result = []
temp = ''

for s in ls:
    if s.startswith('PTE'):
        if temp != '':
            result.append(temp)    
        temp = s
    else:
        if temp == '':
            continue
        temp += ' ' + s
result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

**Edit**

For handling the pattern `PTExyz` you can use regular expression. In that case the code will be like this where the line is `s.startswith('PTE')`:

```
re.match(r'PTE\w{3}$', s)
```

Comment: how your code handle `PTE12` or `PTE12345` which is not in form of `PTExyz`?

Comment: @Gahan added the logic with answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work

```
l =['PTE123', '', 'I', 'am', 'programmer', 'PTE345', 'based', 'word','title', 'PTE427', 'how', 'are', 'you']

resultlist = []
s = ' '.join(l)
str = s.split('PTE')

for i in str:
    resultlist.append('PTE'+i)

resultlist.remove('PTE')
print resultlist
```

Comment: according to question exact match is `PTExyz` and this is generating result like that try with `PTE1` `PTE32` or something like that.

Comment: ok i understood then we have to use regex pattern when spliting

Answer (score 1):

It works on a regular expression PTExyz

```
import re 

l =['PTE123', '', 'I', 'am', 'programmer', 'PTE345', 'based', 'word',
   'title', 'PTE427', 'how', 'are', 'you']
pattern = re.compile(r'[P][T][E]\d\d\d')

k = []

for i in l:
    if pattern.match(i) is not None:
        k.append(i)

s = ' '.join(l)

str = re.split(pattern, s)
str.remove('')
for i in range(len(k)):
    str[i] = k[i] + str[i]

print str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list =['PTE123', '', 'I', 'am', 'programmer', 'PTE345', 'based', 'word','title', 'PTE427', 'how', 'are', 'you']

>>> index_list =[ list.index(item) for item in list if "PTE" in item]

>>> index_list.append(len(list))

>>> index_list

[0, 5, 9, 13]

>>> [' '.join(list[index_list[i-1]:index_list[i]]) for i,item in enumerate(index_list) if item > 0 ]
```

**Output**

```
['PTE123  I am programmer', 'PTE345 based word title', 'PTE427 how are you']
```